# How do I scroll HTML textbox to the end?

Tags: javascript, html

If the content of a HTML textbox is longer than the textbox width, part of it is hidden and you need to scroll the textbox to see the end.  Is there anyway to scroll it in JS or CSS to the end?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Width**

Here's for an `<input type="text" />` and width.

```
var ta = document.getElementById('temp');
ta.scrollLeft = ta.scrollWidth;
```

And my fiddle is updated to show this.

Here's my previous response with doing it for the height.

**Height**

You can use scrollHeight and scrollTop on an element to do this.

```
var ta = document.getElementById('temp');
ta.scrollTop = ta.scrollHeight;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/derekaug/JGqtA/

Comment: Wish I could upvote this twice!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="longBox" type="text" value="mycurrtext" size="30" 
       onfocus="this.value = this.value;" name="longBox"/>
```

I would suggest this, simply when the input fields get's the focus the content is "set" so you automatically jump to the end.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question; there's no indication that it's an input field, so it could just be a text box he's progressively adding text to from the browser itself, and he wants it to stay scrolled to the bottom.