# dynamically increase input type text textbox width according to the characters entering into it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

I have a `textbox` where the user can enter any number of characters, But I want its **width to be increased dynamically with respect to the number of characters entered into it**.

I have done a workaround shown below and it works partially, it will increase the width dynamically but not so precisely and will hide the first entered characters after a while because of my poor logic applied in it. I've just given a wild cutoff of 17 characters count to start the increment.

**It should start the width increment only if the character count reaches the end of textbox.**

**UPDATE:**

**I am looking to make visible all the characters entered in the field, whereas in default the text box hides the leftmost characters.**

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5QcQK/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txtbox" />
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#txtbox').keypress(function() {
    var txtWidth = $(this).width();
    var cs = $(this).val().length;

    if(cs>17){
       $(this).width(txtWidth+5);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have tried this code and it works fine.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function Expand(obj){
      if (!obj.savesize) obj.savesize=obj.size;
      obj.size=Math.max(obj.savesize,obj.value.length);
     }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <form>
       <input  type="text" size="5" style="font-family:Courier;" onkeyup="Expand(this);">
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Be sure to use mono space fonts in text box, otherwise the size attr. and number of characters won't match

Comment: I suggest using `oninput` method because in mobile if we use keyboard's speech to text then it won't be work

Answer (score 4):

Adding a simple inline code in **onkeyUp** should help

```html
<input type="text" name="fname" onkeypress="this.style.minWidth = ((this.value.length + 1) * 7) + 'px';">
```

Comment: I know this an old question but I added just in-case it helps someone

Comment: The value 7 is random you could change it to whatever best suits you

Comment: suggest using `oninput` method because in speech to text it will not work

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" id="txtbox" size="10"/> 

$('#txtbox').keypress(function() {
        var txtWidth = $(this).attr('size');
        var cs = $(this).val().length-6;
        txtWidth = parseInt(txtWidth);
        if(cs>txtWidth){
           $(this).attr('size',txtWidth+5);    }
    });
```

You were using width field which is actually meant for type = image.
You can get more info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_width.asp).
I have used size attribute which is used to set the size of input tag in pixels. When its 1 it can take 6 characters by default hence -6. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

A solution similar to @Tejas', but doesn't require the font to be mono-space:

The trick is to use `scrollWidth`, which gives us the total string length, even on single-line textboxes without a scrollbar:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9312727/1869660

***NOTE:** I couldn't get this to work in IE, where `scrollWidth` always returned 2 for some reason..*

Some code:

```
function expand(textbox) {
    if (!textbox.startW) { textbox.startW = textbox.offsetWidth; }

    var style = textbox.style;

    //Force complete recalculation of width
    //in case characters are deleted and not added:
    style.width = 0;

    var desiredW = textbox.scrollWidth;
    //Optional padding to reduce "jerkyness" when typing:
    desiredW += textbox.offsetHeight;

    style.width = Math.max(desiredW, textbox.startW) + 'px';
}

...

<input type="text" onkeyup="expand(this);" >
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sphinxxx/sqaoet21/2/)

Comment: A more robust (although slightly more complex) option is to create a new hidden element, populate it with the input's text, and measure its width. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width).

Answer (score 0):

On the x-editable documentation you can find the option type so i guess you have to add data-editable-type="textarea"