# Is there a way to make a textbox auto expand without jQuery?

Tags: html, css

I have set resize to vertical but I would like that when the user fills the textbox then its size expands down. Is there any way this can be done without using an external library like jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamically increase input type text textbox width according to the characters entering into it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727692/dynamically-increase-input-type-text-textbox-width-according-to-the-characters-e)

Comment: Almost. but here OP wants it vertically expanded

Comment: Javascript is allowed?

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a textarea with auto-resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered here already: [Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>autoresizing textarea</title>
<style type="text/css">
textarea {
    border: 0 none white;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
    resize: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var observe;
if (window.attachEvent) {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.attachEvent('on'+event, handler);
    };
}
else {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    };
}
function init () {
    var text = document.getElementById('text');
    function resize () {
        text.style.height = 'auto';
        text.style.height = text.scrollHeight+'px';
    }
    /* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
    function delayedResize () {
        window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
    }
    observe(text, 'change',  resize);
    observe(text, 'cut',     delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'paste',   delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'drop',    delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

    text.focus();
    text.select();
    resize();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
<textarea rows="1" style="height:1em;" id="text"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/hmelenok/WM6Gq/

Credits go to panzi, vote him up here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5346855/1540350

Answer (score 4):

Only in CSS and `contentEditable="true"` attribute.

```
div {
display:inline-block;
border: solid 1px #000;
min-height: 200px;
width: 300px;
}
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ARuce/)